# (Embedding Mono) Parallel activation of domains

Tags: c++, c, scripting, mono, embedding

I'm wondering if it's possible to activate multiple Mono domains and execute them in parallel from **native code**:

I use the following code to activate a domain:

```
///Create a new domain.
m_domain = mono_domain_create();

///Activate the domain.
mono_domain_set(m_domain, 0);
///Invoke some function ...
mono_runtime_invoke (m_method, m_objectInstance, NULL, &exception);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this can be done. Given that the Mono virtual executable runs alongside your C application when it's embedded (and shares the same address space), The best approach would be to launch each domain in a separate process. The easiest way to do this would be to have your code fork multiple processes and each process would manage a separate Mono domain instance. You'd have to write some code to coordinate interprocess communications, particularly application clean-up and shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

From the .NET perspective I'd say: yes

The internet archives were able to get this once-ubiquitous resource back:

http://replay.waybackmachine.org/20070228090021/http://www.gotdotnet.com/team/clr/AppdomainFAQ.aspx